# Is IronRuby being actively developed?

Tags: .net, ruby, ironruby

I am planning to use Ruby and RoR 3.x on .Net was wondering if IronRuby is being actively developed, last I heard over the grapevine about year ago was Microsoft withdrew support for it. Can anyone confirm the state ?

Comment: You may want to search Ruby Inside's archives for updates on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is not code related :), I still want to say something.

Jim and another guy were the only two members in Microsoft that were working on IronRuby. After Microsoft takes the thing they want, they "unpurposely" cut down the support for IronRuby (and IronPython), and Jim's boss asked him if he want to do anything else other than Ruby. He sensed it, and left Microsoft. Soon Microsoft claimed they would *donate* IronRuby to open communities, and they cut off the financial support after about a year. This project is still ongoing, but little code was contributed in the past year due to lack of support on Microsoft .Net and little usage from user end (Ruby is still not so popular)

I wouldn't say IronRuby is discontinued, but it is not so active as you would expect. Try some other Ruby implementation. I personally do not like .Net anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronRuby) their last stable release was 22 months ago. They had a preview release 11 months ago. It looks like as of 2010 they have one member of the IronRuby team on staff at Microsoft (may not still be the case).

I'd be quite hesitant to rely on it for any longstanding project.

I would check out [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/). It's probably not going to be viable if you need .net though.

Comment: thanks. My worst fears came true :( sigh ... here is the official Eulogy http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2010/08/start-spreading-news-future-of-jimmy.html